# From Ubuntu machine I want to send a file to other user via email automatically with out any manual work

Tags: linux, shell-script, email

Is there any way of sending a file with out any authentication from linux machine to the user email address?

I want to send a file from a user machine to other user email address with out SMTP server.If yes we can send it from gmail it should be done automatically through a script there should not be any manual work for the user.

Comment: So, you want to send an e-mail **without** installing smtp on your server?

Comment: Yes I wanna send an automatic email by attaching a file with out smtp server.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP is a requirement (Simple Mail Transport Protocol).  There are ways to configure [sendmail with the GMail SMTP relay](https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-gmail-as-sendmail-email-relay).

## Install and configure sendmail

As root user on a Debian system.

```
apt-get install sendmail mailutils sendmail-bin
mkdir -m 700 /etc/mail/authinfo
cd /etc/mail/authinfo
#hash your gmail password info
makemap hash gmail-auth <<<'AuthInfo: "U:root" "I:YOUR GMAIL EMAIL ADDRESS" "P:YOUR PASSWORD"'
#don't save your bash history because of password info
unset HISTFILE
```

Put bellow lines into your sendmail.mc configuration file right above first "MAILER" definition line:

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`[smtp.gmail.com]')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash -o /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth.db')dnl
```

Re-build sendmail's configuration:

```
make -C /etc/mail
```

Reload sendmail:

```
/etc/init.d/sendmail reload
```

## Test sendmail

```
echo "A simple message" | mail -s "Some subject" somebody@example.com
```

Comment: I am getting an error while installing

Comment: I am getting the erro Errors in generating sendmail.cf
*** ERROR: FEATURE() should be before MAILER()
*** MAILER(`local') must appear after FEATURE(`always_add_domain')*** ERROR: FEATURE() should be before MAILER()
*** MAILER(`local') must appear after FEATURE(`allmasquerade')*** ERROR: FEATURE() should be before MAILER()

Answer (score 1):

> Yes I want to send an automatic email by attaching a file with out smtp
>   server

In that case, I would use Python (and have done in the past, although not with attachments). Sending e-mail with Python is simply a couple of `import`'s away.

Here below is one example that I threw together quickly just now, using a Gmail address:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import smtplib
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Your login credentials
sender = "you@gmail.com"
emailPasswd = "yourpassword"

# Who are we sending to
receiver = "whoever@someplace.com"

# The path to the file we want to attach
fileToAttach = "att.txt"

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = "Here's an e-mail with attachment"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver
body = "Mail with attachment"
bodyText = MIMEText(body, "plain")

# Now we try to add the attachment
try:
    att = open(fileToAttach)
    attachment = MIMEText(att.read())
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=fileToAttach)
except IOError:
    print("Could not add attachment {}".format(fileToAttach))
    exit(1)

# "Attach" both the attachment and body to 'msg'
msg.attach(bodyText)
msg.attach(attachment)

# Connect and send e-mail
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(sender, emailPasswd)
server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

This works, but not until you have done **[this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)**. If you don't allow "less secure apps to access your [Gmail] account" you will **not** be able to log in using a script. Instead, you will get a `SMTPAuthenticationError` (error code `534`). See **[here](http://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-gmail-using-python/)** for a good reference.

Now, perhaps needless to point out, but I will do it anyway; my little code snippet above works for `txt` attachments. If you want to attach an image for instance, you will have to import the corresponding module: `from email.mime.image import MIMEImage`

Also, if you don't want to "hard code" the attachment file, you can simply pass it as an argument. If the script is called `./pySmtp.py`, call it like this:

```
./pySmtp.py att.txt
```

If so, change the code into this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import smtplib
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Your login credentials
sender = "you@gmail.com"
emailPasswd = "yourpassword"

# Who are we sending to
receiver = "whoever@someplace.com"

# The path to the file we want to attach
fileToAttach = sys.argv[1]

[rest of code stays the same]
```

As for the "automatic" part, you will have to choose that yourself depending on your needs.